# Find the top x and y co-ordinates of a circle

Tags: python

The below code is used to print out the radius, area and co-ordinates of the top point.

I am struggling with the last part of that. Here is my code:

```
pi = 3.14

class Circle(object):
    def __init__(self, x0, y0, R):
        self.x0, self.y0, self.R = x0, y0, R

    def area(self):
        return pi*self.R**2

    def circumference(self):
        return 2*pi*self.R

c = Circle(2, -1, 5)
print('A circle with radius %g at (%g, %g) has area %g' % (c.R, c.x0, c.y0, c.area()))
```

This code gives out the radius and the area just about fine but I don't know what to do to get the top point of the circle.

Comment: Do you know how to do that mathematically on a piece of paper? If yes, convert it to Python. If not, this question belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well this is trivial as a mathematical quesiton. It's just (x0, y0+R)

Answer (score 0):

```
pi = 3.14

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, x0, y0, R):
        self.x0, self.y0, self.R = x0, y0, R

    def area(self):
        return pi*self.R**2

    def circumference(self):
        return 2*pi*self.R
    def maxPoint(self):
        return (self.x0, self.y0+self.R)

circle = Circle(1,1,1)
print( circle.maxPoint() )
```